# Script that stores multiple values from JSON dictionary into array

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json

I have over 1000s of dictionaries in JSON after an API request. How do create a script that iterates over **all** dictionaries and stores the values of **one** of the key-value pairs?

example

```
},"testData"
{
    "testJSON": "test",
    "phone": null,
    "address: "122 main st"
}, "testData1"
{
    "testJSON": "test1",
    "phone": null,
    "address: "123 main st"
},
```

For example, how do I get the "address" field of every single JSON dictionary?

Comment: Is it "one of the key-value pairs", or "every single JSON dictionary"? Also your JSON example is incorrectly formatted. Is it a list of JSON dictionaries?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yes it's a list of json dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach loop to iterate over the keys of the object

```js
var a={"testData":
{
    "testJSON": "test",
    "phone": null,
    "address": "122 main st"
}, "testData1":
{
    "testJSON": "test1",
    "phone": null,
    "address": "123 main st"
}};
Object.keys(a).forEach(e=>console.log(a[e].address))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse your json, like this:

`var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

then you could iterate your json keys and do something with the root values, like such:

```
for(var el in json)
{
    console.log(json[el]) // will log every root element
    console.log(json[el].phone) // will log phone of each element
}
```

example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ky6dzen/

Answer (score 0):

In python this can be done like this:

```
data = [{
    "testJSON": "test",
    "phone": null,
    "address: "122 main st"
}, "testData1"
{
    "testJSON": "test1",
    "phone": null,
    "address: "123 main st"
}]

my_array = []

for obj in data:
    my_array.append(obj['address'])

print(my_array)
```

Hope this is what you were after :)